# Combining layout_weight and maxHeight?

Tags: android, layout

I have the following "button bar" layout setup:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:maxHeight="86px"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/home_button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/level_button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/home_button"/>
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/help_button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/level_button"/>
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/sound_button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
  <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.9"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want the button bar (the RelativeLayout) height to be 10% of the screen height, so I used layout_weight="0.1" + layout_weight="0.9", but no more than 86 pixels, so I tried to use maxHeight="86px", but this doesn't work.

Do you have any clue how to achiveve 10% height combined with constant maximum height layout restriction, please?

Comment: Unfortunately, the API of `RelativeLayout` does not include an attribute `maxHeight` (neither does `View` or `ViewGroup`). That's why it is not respected in your code, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly easy and probably the cleanest solution to subclass `LinearLayout` and create your own layout calculation.

Just override `onLayout()` and `onMeasure()`.

Comment: Thanks, that's enough answer for me for now but to consider this question as anwered completely, it would be nice to put some code here. I may do that soon...